# How can i prove how many solutions has this equation:$ x^3-3x+b=0$

Tags: derivatives, roots

How can i prove how many solutions has this equation: $x^3-3x+b=0$
This is what I have done, but I got stuck when I try to prove b for $R+$ and $R-$

If $b=0$ so $f'(x) = x^3-3x -> f'(x) = 0 -> x^3-3x = 0 -> x(x^2-3) -> x1 = 3$ and $x2 = +- √3$

If $b = R+$ and $≠ 0 -> f'(x) = 3x^2-3$ and $f''(x) = 6x$
$f(1) = -2+b$
$f(2) = 2+b$
I do not know if $f(1)$ or $f(2)$ are $> 0$ or $< 0$

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem, thanks

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra guarantees 3

Comment: How many complex solutions or how many real solutions?   What's the question?

Comment: @mjw How many real solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the shape of cubic curves, at most they can have two "hips". We can find the location of these by locating the maxima and minima of the curve:

$$f'(x) = 3x^2-3 = 0 \implies x = \pm 1$$

which gives local max and min for $b=0$ at $\pm 2$, which gives us three cases graphically:

If $|b| < 2$, then the curve will have three real roots.

If $|b| =  2$ then the curve will have two real roots (with one being repeated).

If $|b| > 2$ then the curve only has one real root.

Comment: When you find the local max and min, why you say that is for b = 0, I do not understand that part. Thanks.

Comment: We have to plug in to the function to find numbers, and it was easiest to visualize when b is "turned off".

Comment: It doesn't matter what $b$ is or if $b$ is "on" or "off".  The minimum will *always* be at $x =1$ and $f(x) = 2-b$ and the max will *always* be at $x = -1$ and $f(x) =2+b$.  The issues are if the max/min are neg,pos, or 0. Which is the same question as whether $b$ is more, less or between -2 or 2.

Comment: @fleablood, yes, and it was easiest to present this information a certain way. Your point?

Comment: If $|b|=2$, the curve has three real roots, two of which are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function $f(x)=x^3-3x$.  $f(x)$ has relative extrema of $-2$ and $2$.  As such, if $|b|\leq2$, then the equation will have three real roots.  Otherwise, the equation will have one real root and two complex roots.